# How can I synchronize Google Docs with my desktop files?

Tags: google-drive

How can I synchronize the files I have on Google Docs with the ones on my desktop?

I know it used to implemented via Google Gears and then they pulled it to work on a HTML5 solution (although that was aimed at offline editing rather than desktop sync).

Is there a way I can enable sync between Google Docs and my desktop (a la Dropbox)?

Answer (score 2):

The latest info is that you can now install a Google Docs Offline "app" from the Chrome Web Store which provides a read-only view of your documents. You can read the latest on [this blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/09/offline-google-docs.html).

You can do similar things with the GMail app... although that's not read-only.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to synchronize Google Docs with the desktop using Google Drive (which didn't exist when this question was first posted.) Google Drive will synchronize all files in a specific folder with Google Docs, although its "free" storage option only allows up to 5 GB of storage space.